# .htaccess : date range help

Tags: php, .htaccess, date-range

Hi my URL is something  like 
http://www.mysite.come/events.php?eid=10

Event starting date is 01-07-2011

Event name : summer trip

I want to display the above URL to be like
http://www.mysite.com/events/01/07/2011/summer-trip

Does this make sens!?

I will appreciate all your answers, please help as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to send the date in a friendly format, it's quite a simple redirection:

```
# Untested example
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})/.* events.php?date=$3-$2-$1
```

However, mod_rewrite won't do magic. There's no way to obtain `10` from `01/01/2011/summer-trip`.

---

**Edit:** I guess I should not take the question literally and provide some hints. If you want to link events by a friendly string, you need to do a couple of internal changes:

1. Add a new column to the events table in your database and make it unique (most DBMS allow to create unique indexes). That new column (let's call it `url_title`) will hold the friendly string.
2. Adjust your PHP script so it takes the `url_title` as argument, rather than the numeric key.

And your mod_rewrite rule will be something like this:

```
# Again, untested
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}/([^/]+)/?$ events.php?url_title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I have some code that also can do that same what you guys just explained earlier. My code is 

RewriteRule ^events/([0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ evnts.php?edate=$1&ename=$2
My prblem here is , am using smarty and this will change my javascript and CSS path..Any idea What am doing wrong here!?

Comment: @Nuhman, that's an entirely different subject. If you use relative paths, you can't move documents around freely. Use absolute paths instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's a catch all redirect - if a file doesn't exist to match a request, the request is passed to index.php with the original url. (it's how most of the frameworks, wordpress etc do it)

Then you will have $_GET['url'] available in index.php, which you can parse in php and do whatever needs doing to check for/load relevant content.

Note that you need to ensure you implement a 404 error in PHP here - as apache will never 404 itself any more.

Comment: Only the part on how to compile the redirect URL and how to redirect then is missing.